# Laravel 5.1, update multiple values from checked checkbox

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

In Laravel 5.1, I need to update multiple values from checked checkbox.

I can edit some registries from a table by clicking the edit button for each registry, and that button send me to the `edit` view

(This is de edit view for a single registry)
[image]

With the url: `http://myapp/someroute/2246/edit` where 2246 is some `id`.

Inside that edit I can update 4 fields. One of those fields is called "my state" and can have the values `1`, `2` or `3`.

Now, I have to make a multi select edit feature, where I can check every row of the table that I need to update simultaneously (each have the `name=someid`) and then click some button called "Validate", and update for evey row only 1 field, the `my state` field, and the new value will be always `1` (in the picture the values are string but thats only for the view).

[image]

The question is: **how can I call the method `update` for every id that I'm selecting in the view? every input checkbox has it's own `name` which is the id of the registry that I will update**.

The `update` method just validate some values from the view and then call some `myedit`method, but in this case I will jump the `update` and go directly to `myedit` which is someting like:

```
public function myedit(Request $request, $id) {
    $obj                  = Self::findOrFail($id);
    $obj->fk_id_comuna    = $req['fk_id_comuna'];
    $obj->fk_id_user      = $usuario_id;
    $obj->date            = \Carbon\Carbon::now();
    $obj->fk_id_my_state  = $estado; //THIS IS THE ONLY FIELD THAT I WILL EDIT, ALWAYS WITH THE SAME VALUE `1`
    $obj->save();
```

I was trying the make a `form` for that `Validate` button but I don't know how to handle multiple id in one call on the `edit` method.

```
<form action="{!! route('myroute.update', ['id' => [HERE, HOW CAN I PASS MULTIPLE ID FROM THE CHECKED CHECKBOX] ]) !!}" method="POST">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" value="Validar" />
</form>
```

I was thinking on a javascript function which collect in a array every checked checkbox name and call the `myedit` method directly, without the `form`of the view, could be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About passing multiple values as one `Request` value.
Assume you have form like this:

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="checkbox" name="options[]" value="foo"/>foo<br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="options[]" value="bar"/>bar<br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="options[]" value="buz"/>buz<br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Your `request('options')` would be an array: `["foo", "bar", "buz"]`.
Than you can iterate over `options` using foreach.

Inside your `update` method you can go with:

```
foreach ($option as request('options')) {
    //put your previous code here, so it'd be applied for every option
}
```

Comment: Thanks, and nice, it's a good starting point. I will work based on this, and I'll pick it as the correct one if this helps me to make this works.

Comment: I did it with javascript, I will pick your answer as the correct one because that foreach gave me the whole idea. I'll put my own answer of what I did.

Answer (score 1):

In JS I did this:

```
var optionsChecked = [];
    $('.options:checkbox:checked').each( function(){
    optionsChecked .push($(this).val());
});
```

Then in ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data: {'id': optionsChecked },
    etc
```

Then in PHP:

```
$all = $request->input('id');
foreach ($all as $id){
    //whole obj->* = *;
    $obj->save();
}
```